# how to create a custom class to determine type of press by type of button

Tags: actionscript-3

Hey guys I wanted to ask you guys how you would do this because i am new to programming i am still trying to figure out how to do this.

i am building an app with air and i have several buttons with switch cases.

now all my buttons are movieclips buttons and so when you click them they do go to the clicked image and back to the up image.

plus some buttons i would like to have a long press function that will increment faster.

i hope i am making any senses here

---

here is some of my plus and minus buttons

```
    master.pages.numPlayers.minusBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, incrementAmount);
    master.pages.numPlayers.plusBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, incrementAmount);
    master.pages.numBuyIns.minusBtn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, incrementAmount);
    master.pages.numBuyIns.plusBtn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, incrementAmount);
    master.pages.numPayouts.minusBtn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, incrementAmount);
    master.pages.numPayouts.plusBtn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, incrementAmount);
```

this is the function handler with my switch cases i would like with these buttons to have 2 types of behaviors with long press increment faster and just regular click increment one by one

```
private function incrementAmount(event:MouseEvent):void {
    switch (event.currentTarget.name) {
        // number of players
        case  "minusBtn1" :
            if (numPlayers >= 3) {
                numPlayers--;
                firstBuild();
                trace("minus");
            }
            break;

        case  "plusBtn1" :
               numPlayers++;
               firstBuild();
               trace("plus");
            break;

        // number of buy ins money
        case  "minusBtn2" :
            if (numBuyIns >= 1) {
                numBuyIns--;
                firstBuild();
                trace("minus");
            }
            break;

        case  "plusBtn2" :
               numBuyIns++;
               firstBuild();
               trace("plus");
            break;

        // number of payouts
        case  "minusBtn3" :
            if (numPayouts >= 2) {
                numPayouts--;
                firstBuild();
                trace("minus");
            }
            break;

        case  "plusBtn3" :
               numPayouts++;
               firstBuild();
               trace("plus");
            break;

    }
}
```

other buttons with regular click behavior

```
private function onClickTab(event:MouseEvent):void {
    switch (event.currentTarget.name) {
        case  "chips" :
            master.pages.x = 20;
            break;

        case  "payout"  :
            master.pages.x = -704;
            break;

        case  "timer" :
            master.pages.x = -1457;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PlusButton extends Button
{
    private var m_blnSpedUp:Boolean = false;
    private var m_tmr:Timer = new Timer(1500, 1); // use whatever number of
                                                  // milliseconds you prefer here

    public function PlusButton()
    {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOWN, onDown);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.UP, onUp);
    }

    private function onDown(pEvent:MouseEvent):void
    {
        // increment here
        if (!m_blnSpedUp)
        {
            // start the timer here
        }
    }

    private function onUp(pEvent:MouseEvent):void
    {
        // stop the timer here
    }

    private function tick(pEvent:TimerEvent):void
    {
        m_blnSpedUp = true;
        // speed up here
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will get you started, if I understood your question right.  Try using this as your starting point.

Comment: hmmm its almost what im looking for maybe i should show you my code to see its that and how i can integrated it

Comment: i have never seen pevent? what is that private function onDown(pEvent:MouseEvent):void
    {
        // increment here
        if (!m_blnSpedUp)
        {
            // start the timer here
        }
    }

Comment: Basically after the first addEventListener is called, whenever the left mouse button is pressed down (not necessarily clicked) on that button, it'll create an event that'll be handled at least partially by that function.  Whenever the event is created, onDown is called, and pEvent will be the "press down" event that was created.  It's a similar situation for onUp and tick, but you'll probably need to handle at least tick with a little more complexity.

Comment: As far as integration goes, you may wish to just forgo both the MouseEvent.CLICK event listeners and the switch statement (specifically for the buttons with long click functionality).  You really need to listen more for like MouseEvent.DOWN and MouseEvent.UP for them, at least at first.  Also the switch statement you have is in the containing class and is handling everything as a group, but the paradigm used in my example is trying to contain as much as possible within individual buttons.  You could mix and match a little bit though, but this should get you started.